# php bcrypt 505 error

Tags: php, hash, string-hashing

I am trying to use a simple hash for users emails and passwords.
But when I run the following php script that is called on an ajax request i fet a 505 error.

```
<?php

$user = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$email = $user->email;
$pass = $user->pass;
$cpass = $user->cpass;
$ssid = $user->ssid;
$type = $user->type;
$date = $user->regtime;

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
}

$validateEmail = "SELECT `Email` FROM `newUsers` WHERE `Email` = '$email' ";


$newVar = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$validateEmail)) {
     if ($result->num_rows == 0){   
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `newUsers`(`email`, `type`, `date`, `ssid`, `hashpass`) VALUES ('$email', '$type', '$date', '$ssid', '$newVar')";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If i remove the hash attempt and leave the pass word as it is received the password gets inserted so I believe it is the hashing function that is causing the 505. Can anyone see what is going wrong with my hash attempt?

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP log file?

Comment: Thank you for that.
It says I am calling an undefined function.
I understand why I got that error, but how do I include the encryption library?

Comment: You need to `require` or `include` the Bcrypt php file